# Spiral enlargements on desmos

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, desmos

If you toggle the slider for n the point moves in a spiral. Is there a way to plot the curve for all values of n?

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kmdmfazsyy

Comment: two ways, you can make n into a list, or use t instead of n and make a smooth parametric curve....   https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o4pdpyuvkr

Comment: The general equation for the spiral should be something like $r=k^\theta$